# Workspace faulty with TFS saying "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am struggling to solve a problem with Team Foundation Server (yeah, I should just go with Git, I know...). We are working on a mid-sized solution (<20 projects) and suddenly in my workspace I cannot make check-ins or check-outs anymore. Everytime I try to, I get a very generic error message:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

This is either shown in a dialog box, in the output window of Team Foundation Server or at the top of the Team Explorer window in Visual Studio 2013.

I already tried deleting the TFS cache located under

`C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`

and

`C:\Users\[my username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Team Explorer`

Cleaning the solution does not help, and neither does restarting Visual Studio. Other members of my team still can do check-ins and check-outs. Also I found that the issue is not only related to this solution (although it was the only one I have been working on the last few weeks). Regardless what project I try to open, I get the same error message from TFS. However, if I choose another workspace and try to open projects from there, no error appears and all just works as usual.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue (at least temporarily) by changing to another workspace and checking out from there. Here are the steps I went through:

1. Go to `"File"`-> `"Source Control"` -> `"Advanced"` -> `"Workspaces..."` and add a new Workspace
2. Open the `"Source Control Explorer"` window and make sure you have the new workspace selected in the upper combobox. *Note: You may get several dialog boxes with the error message stated above.*
3. Select your solution from the left folder tree and right-click on it
4. Choose `"Get latest version"` and the Map dialog will appear. Choose a new folder. *Perhaps you could have renamed the original folder and reuse the same location then...*
5. Now make the first check-out and that's it!

Comment: BTW: We *really* are in the process of migrating all of our TFS and SVN repositories to Git, so I think until then I can live with this "workaround"...
Though, if anybody knows how to better solve the issue at hand, you are welcome to share! I am still curious what else I could have done...

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when we were migrating to new tfs and new Gated build with the same was created for the same branch. After disabling renaming/disabling new build issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual studio, Delete the ".vs" hidden folder, and try again.